# Angular UI router doesn't process the resolve function when i use async/await feature?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, async-await

I've been trying to render certain template related to a state and component according to this [article](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component)

In my project running under dev-server it all works fine and when I execute `$state.go("home")` the component template is loaded how I expect but when I do this in a testing environment, this doesn't work.

Before, in testing, when I use the "old way" using "template" instead "component" with ui-router, execute `$rootScope.$digest()` was enough for add the template inside the `<div ui-view></div>` but using this new way this doesn't work anymore.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Edit**: I've been trying to deeply understand the problem and I see that the problem is related to the HTTP request that was done. Maybe it's related to the way that my promise resolves on the resolve callback using async/await. Please check the Service:

**Service**

```js
export class TodoService {
    constructor($http, BASE_URL) {
        this.http = $http;
        this.url = `${BASE_URL}/todos`
    }
    async getTodos() {
        const apiResponse = await this.http.get(this.url)
        return apiResponse.data.todos
    }
}
```

**Router**

```js
import '@uirouter/angularjs'

export function routes($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: true,
    })

    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            component: "todoList",
            resolve: {
                todosList: TodoService => TodoService.getTodos()
            }
        })
}
```

**Test**

```js
import { routes } from "routes"
import { TodoListComponent } from "components/todoList.component"
import { TodoService } from "services/todo.service"

describe("TodoListComponent rendering and interaction on '/' base path", () => {
    let componentDOMelement
    let stateService

    beforeAll(() => {
        angular
            .module("Test", [
                "ui.router"
            ])
            .config(routes)
            .constant("BASE_URL", "http://localhost:5000/api")
            .component("todoList", TodoListComponent)
            .service("TodoService", TodoService)
            //I enable this for better logs about the problem
            .run(['$rootScope','$trace', function($rootScope, $trace) {
               $trace.enable("TRANSITION")
             }])
    })
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("Test"))

    beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, $compile, $state, $httpBackend) => {
        //build the scene
        //1st render the root element of scene: We needs a router view for load the base path
        let scope = $rootScope.$new()
        componentDOMelement = angular.element("<div ui-view></div>")

        $compile(componentDOMelement)(scope)
        scope.$digest()
        
         document.body.appendChild(componentDOMelement[0]) //This is a hack for jsdom before the $rootScope.$digest() call
        //2nd let's create a fake server for intercept the http requests and fake the responses
        const todosResponse = require(`${__dirname}/../../stubs/todos_get.json`)
        $httpBackend
            .whenGET(/.+\/todos/)
            .respond((method, url, data, headers, params) => {
                return [200, todosResponse]
            })

        //3rd Let's generate the basic scenario: Go at home state ("/" path)
        $state.go("home")
        $rootScope.$digest()
        $httpBackend.flush()
    }))

    it("Should be render a list", () => {
        console.log("HTML rendered")
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll("html")[0].outerHTML)
    })
})
```

The HTML result that not rendering

```js
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
  display:none !important;
}
ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{
  position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><!-- uiView: -->
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I traced the stateChange before the HTML:

```
console.log node_modules/@uirouter/core/_bundles/ui-router-core.js:1276
    Transition #0-0: Started  -> "Transition#0( ''{} -> 'home'{} )"

console.log node_modules/@uirouter/core/_bundles/ui-router-core.js:1282
    Transition #1-0: Ignored  <> "Transition#1( ''{} -> 'home'{} )"

console.log node_modules/@uirouter/core/_bundles/ui-router-core.js:1313
    Transition #1-0: <- Rejected "Transition#1( ''{} -> 'home'{} )", reason: Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 5, message: The transition was ignored, detail: "undefined")
```

I see a problem in a transition but no reason was given.

========================================================================

**Edit 2**
**Finally we found the problem but I can't figure out the real problem**. I created a branch in my project for showing the problem. This it's related to `async/await` javascript feature:

```
export class TodoService {
    constructor($http, BASE_URL) {
        this.http = $http;
        this.url = `${BASE_URL}/todos`
    }
    //Interchange the comment on the getTodos method and run `npm run tdd` for see the problem:
    //When async/await doesn't used, the html associated to the resolve in the
    // "/" route that used this service, the promise was resolved that expected.
    //The idea for this branch it's research about the problem and propose a way
    //for we can use async/await on the production code and on the testing environment
    async getTodos() {
        const apiResponse = await this.http.get(this.url)
        return apiResponse.data.todos
    }
    // getTodos() {
    //     return this.http.get(this.url).then(res => res.data.todos)
    // }
}
```

[The repository](https://github.com/gpincheiraa/angularjs-tdd-jest/blob/async/await-integration-doesnt-work/src/services/todo.service.js)

So my new Questions are:

- **Why the way that I use the async/await functionality it's not compatible with the ui-router resolve on testing environment but in production code it works?**
- **Maybe it's related to $httpBackend.flush() call?**

**Edit 3**
The issue [3522](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3522) reported in angular UI router repository

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that `async`/`await` uses native promises but your component needs an Angular promise (like the ones returned by `$http`)

Comment: I may just guess. I will just tell what I know. Async/await feature is just an experimental feature and supported in very limited amount of runtimes. Transplitter uses state machine to emulate async/await. This state machine creates simple promises instead of extended once created by $q service. Try to compare actual code which runs on different environments.

Comment: I have noticed in your repository that you don't use babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator. What will happen if you plug it in?

Comment: @EduardLepner Using the "transform-regenerator" babel plugin and "stage-3" it's enough for my production code. I've been trying add babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator but still doesn't work. About your another response, if the promise created for the runtime it's not the promise expected by $q service, why this work if i run the code using my `npm start` script and see this work on the browser? Maybe could be a problem related to the `$httpBackend` mock service because this not work only in the test environment?

Comment: I have pulled your project and run all tests. It works on my machine.

Comment: @EduardLepner Please check now, in the branch `async/await-integration-doesnt-work`. Run `npm run tdd` and see that 3 tests are failing.
 I pushed a not-working example showing the html result. If you go to the `src/services/todo.service.js` and swap the method `async getTodos` by the not-async/await version, you will see that all works fine and the html was rendered.

Comment: The example is too massive to follow. The reason why it can work differently in tests is because ngMock has different implementations for time-related services. This allows tests to be synchronous. But async/await is asynchronous and breaks synchronous workflow. *TodoListComponent rendering...* tests are synchronous, there's no chance that they will work right with async functions. And the most important thing here is that unit tests shouldn't be performed with real router. There are too many moving parts, and this will lead to complex issues that are hard to debug.

Comment: As for async/await in general, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119519/3731501 . async/await lead to some pitfalls that result from the fact that native promises don't involve digests. so a digest should be triggered after each promise in order to make it work as expected (again, there can be problems with ngMock due to the way how $q promises behave there).

Comment: use plugin to convert `async/await` to `promises`, you can use [async-to-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-async-to-promises)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that angular expects an angular Promise that's why your then will work but your await won't, you can solve this by using a library like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-async-await or make a construction like they're demonstrating here https://medium.com/@alSkachkov/using-async-await-function-in-angular-1-5-babel-6-387f7c43948c

Good luck with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess based on my understanding of the way `resolve`-ers work and what `ngMock` does. In your first example, your `resolve` for `getTodos` does not return until the `$http` promise has resolved, at which point you pluck the value off the response and return it. However, `resolve`-ers expect a `$q.Promise` value as a sentinel to hold the rendering of the router until it resolves. In your code, depending on how it's transpiled, the `await` and `return` call likely doesn't produce the correct sentinel value, so it's treated like a synchronous response.

One way to test would be to request the `resolve`-er in the controller for your `todolist` component and inspect the value. I'll bet it's *NOT* a `$q.Promise`, although it might be a native Promise.

When using `resolve`, though, just chain the Promise by adding a `then` and return it. The router will handle the rest.

Or better, switch to Observables! (/me ducks incoming tomatoes)