# Return value from service once $resource promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I have such working code:

Service (factory?):

```
myApp.factory('MyService', ['$q','$resource', 'MyResource',
    function ($q, $resource, MyResource) {

        return {
            getRoles: function () {
                return MyResource.getRoles(); //MyResource makes API calls using $resource 
            } } });
```

Controller:

```
$scope.Roles = MyService.getRoles();
$scope.Roles.$promise.then(function () { $scope.RolesCount = $scope.Roles.length; });
```

What I'd like to do is to create such function in MyService that will return number of roles once getRoles is resolved so I can use it in controller like this:

```
$scope.RolesCount = MyService.getRolesCount();
```

and then in html

```
{{RolesCount}}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this since my getRolesCount() method needs to return something so I can't use $promise.then() inside MyService. I'll try to update my question's title once I come up with something more accurate.

Comment: You should redefine getRoles action with `actions` option and provide transformResponse, something like this.

Comment: Yeap but it sounds like manipulating on Resource/Repository layer. What if I want to process returned data on Service layer (isn't it what it is for?) and then return result to controller (as object reference same way as $resource does it)?

Comment: Yes, a service is more suitable place. But in your case none of these approaches work because `then` not just transforms the response but unwraps its value. Moreover, you don't really need to do this with resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If server response needs to be transformed in a service, then `then` should be moved there. However, it's not practical or possible if `then` is supposed to unwrap a promise and assign a value to scope, like in the code above.

`$resource` returns an object that is filled on promise resolution. The way a resource is supposed to be used in view is:

```
{{Roles.length}}
```

When an object is updated, it will be updated in view, too. Assigning the value to another variable is inefficient.

It's impossible to do something like

```
$scope.RolesCount = MyService.getRolesCount();
```

because `getRolesCount` is asynchronous, and the value it resolves with is scalar. It is possible to flatten it with `async..await, (TypeScript or ES2017), but will require additional measures to synchronize control flow with AngularJS digests, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119519/3731501).