# Returned array from function - TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, callback, fetch

I am writing a simple js function to return an array of strings fetched using the fetch API. Whenever I try to run code, I get this error: `TypeError: callback is not a function`

This is my code

```
function getFlavors(franchise, callback) {
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    let flavors= [];
    fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'            
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "franchise": franchise })
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            json.forEach(element => {
                flavors.push(element.flavor)
            });
            // console.log(flavors);
            callback(flavors);    <-- VALUES DISPLAYED ON CONSOLE
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

}

let benJerrysFlavors = [];
getFlavors("ben&jerrys",benJerrysFlavors);
```

I am able to see the values on the console but when attempting to return the array from function, I get the callback error

Any ideas as to what might be the issue?

Comment: `benJerrysFlavors` is an array `[]`, cannot be called like `benJerrysFlavors()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be called with a callback function passing the data to it. And you can uptate your array then with the returned data:

```
let benJerrysFlavors = [];
getFlavors("ben&jerrys", (ret) => {
    benJerrysFlavors = ret;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be tied to the scope of the function in this case `getFlavors()`

Comment: Have you tried? All the callbacks work this way, it's a function that you pass as a parameter and then gets executed later on in the other function. Otherwise, it's not a callback

Comment: I tried it, and yes I am tied to the scoped to the function. If I try to use `benJerrysFlavors` outside `getFlavors()` it treats it as an empty array. Essentially I just want to get the data so not sure if a `callback` is the best way to go here

Comment: Well, but you can't place a console log out ot the callback, the function is async so the array won't have the value until the callback gets executed (after the fetch call gets a response). If you don't believe me set a timeout and check benJerrysFlavors value after several secs, it will have the value. The problem is not the callback

Comment: There are other ways to get async response as promises that might be what you want. Callbacks are ok but it all depends on what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365985/callbacks-promises-async-await-in-javascript-still-confusing/48367100

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from:

```
callback(flavors)
```

To:

```
callback.push(...flavors)
```

Comment: I guess with that solution the end result would be `[ [{}, {}] ]`. Array in array.

Comment: @norbitrial, updated. Thank you
https://jsfiddle.net/05cpg6ry/